# NextJS 13 Error: Export encountered errors on following paths

Tags: reactjs, build, next.js13

When trying to build in my nextjs project, version: 13.5.4, I'm encountering this error.

```
> world_legacy@0.1.0 build
> next build

✓ Creating an optimized production build
✓ Compiled successfully
✓ Linting and checking validity of types
✓ Collecting page data
Generating static pages (25/34) \[=== \]
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.
at nd (C:\\Users\\santi\\Dropbox\\PC\\Documents\\webzilla\\paginas\\Oscar el audaz\\WORLD LEGACY\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\compiled\\next-server\\app-page.runtime.prod.js:27:48194)
at nh (C:\\Users\\santi\\Dropbox\\PC\\Documents\\webzilla\\paginas\\Oscar el audaz\\WORLD LEGACY\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\compiled\\next-server\\app-page.runtime.prod.js:27:50922)
at nc (C:\\Users\\santi\\Dropbox\\PC\\Documents\\webzilla\\paginas\\Oscar el audaz\\WORLD LEGACY\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\compiled\\next-server\\app-page.runtime.prod.js:27:34874)
at nd (C:\\Users\\santi\\Dropbox\\PC\\Documents\\webzilla\\paginas\\Oscar el audaz\\WORLD LEGACY\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\compiled\\next-server\\app-page.runtime.prod.js:27:35459)
at nh (C:\\Users\\santi\\Dropbox\\PC\\Documents\\webzilla\\paginas\\Oscar el audaz\\WORLD LEGACY\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\compiled\\next-server\\app-page.runtime.prod.js:27:50922)
at ny (C:\\Users\\santi\\Dropbox\\PC\\Documents\\webzilla\\paginas\\Oscar el audaz\\WORLD LEGACY\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\compiled\\next-server\\app-page.runtime.prod.js:27:53901)
at nm (C:\\Users\\santi\\Dropbox\\PC\\Documents\\webzilla\\paginas\\Oscar el audaz\\WORLD LEGACY\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\compiled\\next-server\\app-page.runtime.prod.js:27:52967)
at nh (C:\\Users\\santi\\Dropbox\\PC\\Documents\\webzilla\\paginas\\Oscar el audaz\\WORLD LEGACY\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\compiled\\next-server\\app-page.runtime.prod.js:27:51168)
at ny (C:\\Users\\santi\\Dropbox\\PC\\Documents\\webzilla\\paginas\\Oscar el audaz\\WORLD LEGACY\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\compiled\\next-server\\app-page.runtime.prod.js:27:53901)
at nd (C:\\Users\\santi\\Dropbox\\PC\\Documents\\webzilla\\paginas\\Oscar el audaz\\WORLD LEGACY\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\compiled\\next-server\\app-page.runtime.prod.js:27:45663)

...MORE ERRORS HERE

> Export encountered errors on following paths:
> /about/page: /about
> /faq/page: /faq
> /page: /\
```

This is my next.config.js

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
// supports-color,
const nextConfig = {
images: {
domains: \[
'localhost',
'res.cloudinary.com',
'lh3.googleusercontent.com',
\],
},
webpack: (config, { isServer }) =\> {
config.experiments = {
...config.experiments,
topLevelAwait: true,
};
return config;
},
};

module.exports = nextConfig;\
```

I've tried npm run build when the problem happened.
I've tried deleting /.next folder and /node_modules and still does not work.